# How to capture AWS Cognito attributes like USERID and PHONENO into MySQL database

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

My application has a lot of features that need 'EMAILID' and 'PHONE NO' of the users. How can these two AWS Cognito attributes that are used for authentication be stored into the back-end MySQL database?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you expect and where you are stuck? Are you saying you want to save these cognito user pool attributes to another MySQL table?

Comment: I would like to know whether it's possible to store/capture the  AWS Cognito attributes such as Email & Phone used for authentication in to a back-end MySQL  tables (ex: Customer table)  ? If yes , How?

Comment: You can use the various APIs to get cognito user details and store them into a table. What language are you using? I query cognito using python's boto3 library.

Comment: we are using JAVA .could you please let me know which API should we use.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the user attributes such as phone number and email using [Cognito Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) and store it into your database directly.